# $ n $ lines intersections

Tags: number-theory, limits, recurrence-relations

As we all know, $ n $ lines which are not coincident may have some intersection points in an Euclid plane. And we define the set of the number of intersection points $ n $ lines can form is $ \mathbb{I} $, and we also define the complementary set $ \mathbb{B} = \{k \; | \; 0 \leq k \leq C_{n}^{2}\} - \mathbb{I} $.

The question is, how can we find the maximum value in the set $ \mathbb{B} $, which we called $ L(n) $. If can't, could you prove that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{L(n)}{n^{2}} = 0 $$

PS. For example, 5 lines may have 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 intersection points, so set $ \mathbb{I} = \{0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\} $
ans set $ \mathbb{B} = \{2, 3\} $, so the $ L(5) = 3 $

Comment: I do not understand the question. Certainly the number of intersection points can be $O(n)$.

Comment: Note that you get more appropriate spacing around the vertical bar in the set-builder notation when you use the `\mid` command instead of the vertical bar.

Comment: What kind of plane?

Comment: Relevant [MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82622/numbers-of-intersection-points-and-lines).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\ell$ be say the $x$-axis, and let $P$ be a point not on the $x$-axis. Pick $n-1$ points $Q_1,\dots, Q_{n-1}$ on $\ell$.

Consider the set of $n$ lines consisting of $\ell$ and the $n-1$ lines $PQ_i$. These determine $n$ intersection points. In this case, $\binom{n}{2}$ minus the number of points is large. (We assume $C_n^2$ is intended to be a name for the binomial coefficient.) If I understand what you mean by $L(n)$, $\lim\frac{L(n)}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

The above is for the projective plane. For the Euclidean plane, one can make the number of intersection points $0$.

Comment: Please forgive my poor English, for example, 4 lines may have 0,1,3,4,5,6 intersection points, so the set $\mathbb{B} = \{2\} $

Comment: OK, an example makes things much clearer, the notation did not. I think $o(n^2)$ is doable in the Euclidean plane.